# submit break point in Chrome not working as expected with jQuery submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My app is using jQuery. And in particular the jQuery submit method in multiple places. I am trying to figure out which submit is being called.

So in Google Chrome, I add a submit break point. But it does not break at the submit call. Instead it breaks within jQuery's source code in a method called add:

[image]

This is not useful to me at all. When I resume the script execution, it never takes me to the submit() call. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger is stopping in the jQuery library because it's the first bit of code to execute as a result of the native [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) event. jQuery handles that event, and then delegates the remaining handling code to you. If you continued to step through the code, you'd eventually get to your own handler.

To avoid this, you can blackbox the jQuery library in the debugger. This will prevent it from stopping in the jQuery code, and go straight to your own code.

Right-click inside the file and click 'Blackbox script', then try again.

[image: jQuery handler]